# How to avoid cleaning data when updating channel

Tags: react-native, getstream-io

We have several fileds of custom information attached to the channel. And time-to-time need to update some of them. But when I try to update one custom field via `channel.update` - all other fields disappear.

One idea was to use spread operator - to include all exister `channel.data` to update an object. But it doesn't seem to be the right way and it gives `UpdateChannel failed with error: "expected string for field "data.config.commands[0]" but got object"` error.

I hope there is a better way rather than keep in mind all custom fields and include all previous values in the update object.

Comment: can you share the code? also keep in mind that `update` replaces all data, it's not a partial update

Comment: That's exact question - how to call `update` without replacing all data, but make a partial update?

Comment: real partial update does not exist; you can try to clone the data object and remove all fields that are reserved like `config`, `type`, `id` (with a bit of trial and error you should get to the right payload)